# boost::asio::async_write with std::string

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost-asio, tcpserver, condition-variable

So my setup is the following:

- Raspberry Pi working as a TCP server with boost asio c++ library;
- TCP Client running on other machine;

The communication is working fine expect for the part that I should be able to send an answer to the client request. To do so I'm using the following code:

```
std::cout << "\tI2C message from Arduino: " << I2CrxBuf_;
boost::asio::async_write(sock_, boost::asio::buffer( I2CrxBuf_.c_str(), sizeof(I2CrxBuf_.c_str()) ), boost::bind(&conn::h_write, shared_from_this()));
std::cout << "Passei o async_write" << std::endl;
```

The thing is that the message prints just fine but then it jumps to the last print without sending the message to the client, and so the client blocks.

The output in the server is the following:

```
I2C message from Arduino: l 1 14.88
Passei o async_write
```

If I send a generic message like this:

```
boost::asio::async_write(sock_, boost::asio::buffer( "Message recevied\n" ), boost::bind(&conn::h_write, shared_from_this()));
```

The client receives the message as it was expected.

I'm pretty sure the problem as to do with the way I'm converting the string to char*, but I not finding a way to make it work.

Comment: `sizeof(I2CrxBuf_.c_str())` is 4 bytes. I think you meant `I2CrxBuf_.size()`.

Comment: Thanks, that true but still not sending...

Comment: Also I have checked and the c.str() method does not removed the '\n ' from the end of the string. 
Since the client needs the message to have it this should not be the problem.

Comment: Not quite sure I understand the problem, but... the value returned from [`std::string::c_str`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) should really be treated as a temporary and, thus, isn't suitable for passing to an asynchronous function such as `async_write`.  If `I2CrxBuf_` is in scope and unmodified for the duration of the write operation then just construct the buffer using that -- `boost::asio::buffer(I2CrxBuf_)` instead.

Comment: Sorry @arrowd that was indeed the problem.

Comment: @G.M. Thanks for the warning I will check if that is a problem. I though that `boost::asio::buffer` only worked with `chat*`argument but it also works the way you pointed. I will use that approach. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sizeof(I2CrxBuf_.c_str())` is wrong. Also, you can do `buffer(I2CrxBuf)` directly. See [docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/buffer.html) for other overloads.

Other than that, realize that the string ***needs*** to stay alive until the end of the async operation (and cannot be modified in the mean time).

All the samples in the documentation have good ideas on how to achieve this.

Comment: Thaks! I have mutex’s to make sure that it doesn’t get modified... but anyway thanks for the warning!

Comment: Mutex can not really work in asynchronous settings. Of course it _can_ if you jump through hoops, make sure all handlers run on a specific thread and you keep the mutex locked for long durations (all of these are design smells) - I really think we can be 90% sure your mutex approach is flawed. How do you keep the string alive? Look at [Asio Strands](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/strands.html) about synchronization on data/resources

Comment: Sorry, In this case I'm using condition_variable... They should do the job right?

Comment: No difference. `condition_variable` implies a locking primitive. I'm happy to review real code. In case you haven't heard about this site: [CodeReview.SE]

Comment: The thing here is that I need the server to stop while I get the answer to the client request on another thread. Is there a better way to do it? Btw thanks for the link I will give it a check.